# How to see what went wrong on a CrossOver app that crashed?

Tags: crossover

I've been using Ubuntu half a year now and I want to know how to diagnose an app for problems.

I have installed Torchlight using Crossover and it used to work but now all I can see is the mouse pointer when I start the app, I want to know why it happens and what I can do to fix it.

Please make your answer applicable to any CrossOver application.

Answer (score 2):

- Check if the dependencies are still active (looks like it needs Visual Basic 2008+ for Torchlight to run).
- If possible start the application through command line and watch for errors.
- Crossover has an option in the start menu to set logging in the 'Run...' command. [Here is a tutorial from before Unity](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/linux/linuxtutorial/debug) (so skip the 1st part). They show here how to set logging for IE6 and similar to that you could try it for Torchlight.
- I would also suggest [their forums](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=6534;forum=1). It is more than likely the people that know what to do can be found there.
- [There is also a separate page for Linux that might be interesting](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/linux).